# How to use a formular to set different number of significant figures in crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports

I have different products using the same report and the difference between all of them is the number of significant figures that each use for the calculated results.

I know that you can set the number of significant figures in crystal for a numeric field, so what I want to do is set this ON CONDITION.

The idea I have is to use an IF statement like this: IF Product_Name = '...' set **??** . So my question is what do I set there?

Comment: can you post a image of your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Select the Product Field
2. Right Click
3. Click on Format Object
4. Click Number
5. Click Customize
6. Click on Formula Editor Button in front of Decimals
7. Enter the following formula

   ```
      if {ProductName}="Product Name 1" then 1 
      else if {ProductName}="Product Name 2" then 2 
      else 3
   ```

This should help

Comment: Thanks a lot, I thought the Decimal had to be put into context.